# How can a web application detect the user's idle time?

Tags: javascript, html

I am working on a browser-based instant messaging client, and this application needs to know when the user is idle, if possible.  Is there a way, in any major browser, for the application to detect the user's idle time system-wide?  Failing that, are there any recommended techniques for detecting when the user was last active in the application itself, and possibly in other pages under the same domain?

Comment: Look into the javascript event handlers for keyboard and mouse activity: http://www.javascriptkit.com/jsref/eventkeyboardmouse.shtml

The user would be idle if they are not invoking one these events after a set period of time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If user goes to different page, we can assume he's not idle, so the problem gets reduced to 'is user active on current page?'

You can set timeout in `onMouseMove` event of body. When timeout fires, you know user's been inactive for some period of time. If it doesn't, and you receive a `onMouseMove` before timeout, you simply clear the timeout.
You can also deal with `onKeyPress` in the same way.

This could be a little harder if user would open many tabs of your page, but I would just use `localStorage` for some way of communication between those tabs.